# Does method jdbcSession() in AppServiceHub create a fresh session each time it is called?

Tags: corda

Our code uses a custom `CordaService` that maintains state in a database table. To query/update the table, the service uses a JDBC Connection object obtained by calling `AppServiceHub.jdbcSession()`.

It is not clear from the documentation if this call creates a fresh (not-in-use) JDBC `Connection` object or if it returns the same `Connection` to all callers. Since our Corda service exposes methods to flows that execute concurrently, this matters.

The [documentation](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.node/-service-hub/jdbc-session.html)
 states that the method

> Exposes a JDBC connection (session) object using the currently configured database.

and that the method

> Returns a new Connection

The second statement suggests that we should get a fresh `Connection` on each call, but in reality concurrent calls appear to return the same `Connection` object.

Can someone clarify what the intended and actual behaviors for this method are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second statement is incorrect. The `jdbcSession` method does not always return a fresh connection object. See https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/4498 (now fixed).

Instead:

- The node creates a pool of connections at start-up

  - If one of these connections breaks, the node adds a new one to the pool
- When a flow starts/is restored from a checkpoint, the node gives the flow a connection from this pool

  - It is possible, but not guaranteed, that by chance a flow will be handed the same connection across multiple suspend/restores
- When a flow suspends/ends, the node returns the flow's connection to the pool

Comment: Can you be more precise than 'not always a fresh connection object'? What's the rationale for (potentially) returning the same connection object to different/concurrent flows?

Comment: Thanks for updating, @joel. We've observed concurrent flows getting the same `Connection` object, which seems to contradict the statement that each flow is given its own connection. While that might be the _desired_ behavior, it does not appear to be the _actual_ behavior. The fix you refer to tells users that they will get "a `Connection`", which is much less specific than your statement above. Without clarity on the relationship between flows and Connections, we are more or less forced to put all database code in a critical section.

Comment: @fixpoint Sorry, I was mistaken. I've updated the answer above based on further discussions. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it does and this behavior makes sense to me. I think it would be good to have this clearly documented. I also assume that the caller of jdbcSession must not close the `Connection` that it receives and it would be good to make that explicit.